# Why is a sum (or discriminated union or disjoint union) the inverse of a product?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around category theory and this question just came to my mind - why is the sum type the inverse of the product type? I mean, I see how arrows are changing directions in the opposite category, but I don't see why sum couldn't contain both components coming to it.

Comment: It isn't the "inverse". It is the "dual".

Comment: Ok, but what's the difference then?

Comment: A sum, by definition, cannot contain both components; it is one **or** the other. This is an alternative meaning of the word *disjoint*. The term "product" is analogous to cartesion product, meaning that it must have both of the components.

Answer (score 1):

They are dual in the sense that one is defined by the mapping in property, and the other by the mapping out property. Every mapping *into* a product, `c -> (a, b)`, is equivalent to a pair of functions `c -> a` and `c -> b`. Every mapping *out* of a coproduct, `Either a b -> c` is equivalent to a pair of functions `a -> c` and `b -> c` (think of pattern matching the `Left a` and `Right b` constructors).

Comment: Yep, that's what I understood from your lectures. However what I was puzzled about was why something that contains one value out of two is dual to something always containing both. Why don't both contain both values? In other words why isn't an ordinary union the dual? But then I came back to your lecture about coproduct and around minute 16 you finish your proof and then it clicked :)